# How to colour xlabs with the corresponding colour of its jitter in a geom_jitter?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to colour the xlabs with the same colour as the point they are labelling, but I am having some trouble.

Each jitter is coloured depending on a specified variable levels, and I want the same for the xlabs.

This is my code to plot the figure:

```
ggplot(coverage_data, aes(x=x_values, y=coverage_data$mean, fill=coverage_data$frecuency))+
  geom_jitter(size=2.5, shape=21, stroke=1.5)+
  scale_fill_manual(name = "frecuency", values =c("deepskyblue4", "gray67", "darkgoldenrod2", "springgreen4", "brown1", "white"))+
  xlab("Id")+
  ylab("max coverage")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(hjust=1, colour = 'black', size = 9))
```

If I declare colour ( in theme(axis.text.x(element_text)) ) as a vector I get an error. Do you know how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Passing a vector of colors generates a warning, but with `ggplot2 3.3.0` (what I'm running) it does work.

Since you didn't share any data I've made some up:

```
frecuency <- rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), 10)
mean <- runif(60, 10, 20)
x_values <- runif(60, 1, 100)

coverage_data <- data.frame(frecuency, mean, x_values, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ggplot(coverage_data, aes(x= x_values, y= mean, fill= frecuency))+
  geom_jitter(size=2.5, shape=21, stroke=1.5)+
  scale_fill_manual(name = "frecuency", values =c("deepskyblue4", "gray67", "darkgoldenrod2", "springgreen4", "brown1", "white"))+
  xlab("Id")+
  ylab("max coverage")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(hjust=1, colour = c("black", "blue", "green", "yellow", "red"), size = 9))
```

> Warning message: Vectorized input to `element_text()` is not
>   officially supported. Results may be unexpected or may change in
>   future versions of ggplot2.

[image]

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

other attached packages:
[1] ggQC_0.0.31     readxl_1.3.1    forcats_0.5.0  
[4] stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_0.8.3     purrr_0.3.3    
[7] readr_1.3.1     tidyr_1.0.2     tibble_2.1.3   
[10] ggplot2_3.3.0   tidyverse_1.3.0
```